# udev rule on mouse

Tags: mouse, security, udev

#### Context

---

I have a Steelseries Rival 700 mouse.

End users can configure this mouse: Polling, sensitivbity, colors and effects, buttons, click macros, tactile effects, OLED display etc. blah blah.

It only has software for Windows and macOS.

I have used Wireshark and VM to gather information on how to configure the mouse, and used a simple script to test simple settings.

End goal is to have a piece of software I can use to configure most of the mouse.

---

#### Question

To write configuration to mouse one have to be super-user. To be able to write directly as end user one could add a udev rule for the mouse. My question is how bad this is.

It has root restrictions for a reason. Making the mouse open in userland is not the best, but how bad is it?

My thought is that it would perhaps be better / possible to create some sort of service that only takes defined sets of changes like the configuration options mentioned above. Then create a separate piece of software that communicate with this service.

Is the extra effort worth it?

Comment: Is it safe? Well, it is depends (user base). But if it gets more interest by too many users , certainly it will make its way to the kernel space as regular drivers.

Comment: If you have this script , already published somewhere ( a git repository) may be better, people may use it as it is for few years.  Add its link to the question.